# I am not able to post new questions even though I have asked good questions in the past

Tags: discussion, question-answer-ban

I have posted a total of 7 questions on CSE. Only one question received downvotes (due to a miscalculation, which I resolved), while I received 7 upvotes on the other 6 questions. Why am I not able to post new questions on CSE?

I just clicked the 'Ask Question' button and this appeared:

[image: message showing account is restricted from posting new questions]

Comment: This has been asked over a dozen times on this Meta. Canonical question on the mother Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997. TL;DR answer regarding the mechanism: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193373/. Diamond mods cannot disengage a question ban.

Comment: @andselisk I wouldn't have asked this question if I didn't have any reason. Only 1 out of 7 questions I posted received downvotes, 5 out of those 7 received upvotes (leaving 1 question that didn't receive upvotes or downvotes). The guidelines say to improve upon my previous questions; however, most of my questions are good and have received upvotes. There doesn't seem to be any good reason for this. I went through the site guidelines and there is nothing that justifies this.

Comment: @andselisk note that the message says "most of your (my) questions need improvement," how can this be the case when most of my questions have received upvotes?

Comment: It is not clear whether the filter also takes a look at the meta questions. It does seem to go across all SE sites.

Comment: Let me re-iterate: mods simply don't know the algorithm that leads to the question ban. I can only speculate how the *deleted* (yes, they count too — you posted 10, not 7 questions as you claim) and downvoted posts in your portfolio of asked questions (clearly, they were not *all* "*good*") played their part and why the ban engaged only now.

Comment: @Karsten I would say these are different and likely not related, and there are different constraints, too: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362850/do-post-bans-work-the-same-way-on-all-per-site-metas

Comment: @andselisk I have not deleted any posts. Please don't speculate. When I first signed up for stack exchange, I had this starry-eyed vision of an open world where people are encouraged to ask, research, discuss, and learn. However, the more I use stack exchange, the more I feel like this website just doesn't do all of that. There is a lack of transparency and communication is very limited.

Comment: @Karsten I have received a question ban on MSE, but I understood the reasons then, because it was reflected in the comments, and I learned from there. While I may still not be perfect, in this instance, I just don't understand what is going on. Nonetheless, I will work on improving my questions and hope that the ban is lifted.

Comment: @ananta Please refrain from accusations that in fact are well better applied to you. I never said *you* deleted your questions, I pointed that you didn't tell the whole truth when you said "*total of 7 questions*" when in fact the current total is 10. Please note that SE sites are strictly for high-quality *questions* and *answers* only, free of charge. They are definitely not discussion forums or a full-fledged learning platforms (although one may well use it as one on their own within the Q&A format).

Comment: @andselisk that's totally my bad, I totally forgot I deleted those 3 questions. Thank you for clarifying the purpose of SE as well. I will improve upon my posts based on this.

Comment: @BuckThorn I agree, though I have plans to edit all my questions and answers for the best chance of getting out of this hitch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this meta, we have [question-answer-ban] as a tag. It is not used consistently (I just added it to this post), but gives you a quick overview of how others have encountered this, and how they have dealt with it.

The good news is that the ban is based on a metric imposed algorithmically. This means there is no human subjectivity involved in making the call. Of course, the call is based on human interactions (well, I hope all of our users are human and not AIs), which are subjective and unpredictable.

The bad news is that the details of the ban metric are undisclosed. However, I think the human interactions on the site give you a sense how to improve questions and answers.

Answer (score 6):

As a rule of thumb:

- Question with positive score: good
- Question with negative score: bad
- Closed question: bad
- Deleted question: bad

A deleted, closed, and negative scoring question is a triple threat. And you need about three well-asked questions to make up for it.

To sum it up, the questions you do not see are causing most of the trouble. (Which was lifted the last time I checked.)
Make your next questions good ones and you'll avoid future rate limiting (probably).